# Solving the equation for y in terms of x

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck and don't know what to do next to solve this equation for $y$ in terms of $x$. Any hints?

$$ y(x_2−x_1)−y_1(x_2−x_1)=x(y_2−y_1)−x_1(y_2−y_1) $$

Comment: Solve the equation for what? $x$? $y$? Also, are you sure you meant the linear-algebra tag, and not the algebra-precalculus tag?

Comment: its equation of a line of the form 
$\frac{y-y1}{x-x1}=\frac{y2-y1}{x2-x1}$

Comment: how did you got that o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation is:
$$y(x_2-x_1)-y_1(x_2-x_1)=x(y_2-y_1)-x_1(y_2-y1)$$
Group everything on the left side of the equation:
$$y(x_2−x_1)-x(y_2−y_1)+x_1(y_2−y_1)-y_1(x_2−x_1)=0$$

As I assume you know $x_1$  $x_2$  $y_1$ and $y_2$, it yields an equation like this:
$$ax+by+c=0$$
with $a = y_1-y_2$; $b = x_2-x_1$ and $c=x_1y_2-y_1x_2$ which are known values.

You then have a affine line of solutions if $a \ne 0$ and $b \ne 0$:
$$x = -\dfrac{by+c}{a}$$
if $b = 0$ and $a \ne 0$, the former equation stands, but can be rewritten:
$y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x = -\dfrac{c}{a}$

if $a = 0$ and $b \ne 0$ you have another affine line of solutions:
$x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y = -\dfrac{b}{c}$.

Finally if $a = b = 0$, there is a solution iff $c = 0$, and this solutions will be all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}²$

Comment: You might want to take another look at your grouping, some signs are off.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for noticing, I've edited my answer